# OAuth2 Password Credential flow

Tags: node.js, authentication, oauth-2.0

Is there any node module where the client communicates with the server through an Oauth2 API  using Resource Owner Password Credentials grant type? Im looking for some client code to call the API's.

Comment: Questions seeking off-site resources are off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out: https://github.com/FrankHassanabad/Oauth2orizeRecipes/wiki/Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials

It supports the full resource owner password credential grant process defined in the RFC